# Oracle 12c query results in sqlplus but not SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I have a single instance called sp_admin with several tables.  One of them is called 'tenant_api_user'.  From sqlplus, I can `select *` from any of the tables, including tenant_api_user (or `select count(*)` etc) and the results are fine.  However, when I run queries against this one specific table in SQL Developer, it always returns zero records.

When I run the `select * from tenant_api_user;` from SQL Developer, it returns 0 records instantly - no waiting.  That same query from sqlplus returns the only record in the table. When I try to update a record that is visible from sqlplus, SQL Developer says `0 rows updated.`

Has anyone experienced this kind of behavior before?  It seems to be isolated to just this table.  SQL Developer doesn't behave this way with any other table.

Comment: Have you input the data in SQL*Plus? If so, have you `commit`ed the data?

Comment: Thanks MT0 - that was it...  Rookie mistake.  Please add this as a solution so I can mark it as the solution.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have entered the data in one session and you have not run a `commit` statement then you will not be able to see the data in another session until it has been committed.

Comment: Thanks MT0 - exactly the issue.